# NoMethodError (undefined method `connect_timeout=' for #<Typhoeus::Request:0x000000000782ded8>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to implement Log-In with Facebook to my app. Everything worked fine in development but for production I had to upgrade the app to https and when I pushed to production, nothing works anymore.

I have no idea how to debug this since it's in production. Any help would be appreciated.

**Those are the server logs:**

```
2018-09-17T19:07:21.708757+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-17T19:07:21.708637 #4]  INFO -- : [c8077522-7674-46e5-97b8-c74456194630] Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 213.190.86.42 at 2018-09-17 19:07:21 +0000
2018-09-17T19:07:21.709189+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-17T19:07:21.709128 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
2018-09-17T19:07:22.442651+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-17T19:07:22.442540 #4]  INFO -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78] Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQDCk0zcgI3_D0ZEuO5l6pWjAbhRgSelpfYcPB_f70hwffFdhs2MRp1rYd1fktORGUhqruLXbB40DXbbbx71zMHD2hH5UyndDQXbWpZ4gIoDuGVqO6IgFMwQuv0Jp_-PVQ2eokb_aW_ZfVY_LkIYPUWqy4fGihmWgd3S4cSlpo9zqV_0m9Ra4avOXQjw5a8VQEq2WNlIsun4J77x4EBzrOh_9xtVG582YV2pZy6tFE83QsvsmNkpBEzmWsV0bnGek94hbnbkpKRmImHfCLD5iyJ3HWZ3uQLG3FypdGZHjo8BtQ23Y2GeD5lnsyGlvqGRX4M&state=f58628a503514d6fd368e47a88f0f1c383e1dbe519b4ad09" for 213.190.86.42 at 2018-09-17 19:07:22 +0000
2018-09-17T19:07:22.443281+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-17T19:07:22.443215 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
2018-09-17T19:07:22.958420+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-17T19:07:22.958291 #4]  INFO -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78] Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
2018-09-17T19:07:22.963677+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-17T19:07:22.962975 #4]  INFO -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78]   Parameters: {"code"=>"AQDCk0zcgI3_D0ZEuO5l6pWjAbhRgSelpfYcPB_f70hwffFdhs2MRp1rYd1fktORGUhqruLXbB40DXbbbx71zMHD2hH5UyndDQXbWpZ4gIoDuGVqO6IgFMwQuv0Jp_-PVQ2eokb_aW_ZfVY_LkIYPUWqy4fGihmWgd3S4cSlpo9zqV_0m9Ra4avOXQjw5a8VQEq2WNlIsun4J77x4EBzrOh_9xtVG582YV2pZy6tFE83QsvsmNkpBEzmWsV0bnGek94hbnbkpKRmImHfCLD5iyJ3HWZ3uQLG3FypdGZHjo8BtQ23Y2GeD5lnsyGlvqGRX4M", "state"=>"f58628a503514d6fd368e47a88f0f1c383e1dbe519b4ad09"}
2018-09-17T19:07:22.987503+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-17T19:07:22.987389 #4] DEBUG -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78]   User Load (3.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "10156065770667984"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-09-17T19:07:22.990121+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-17T19:07:22.990015 #4] DEBUG -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78]    (1.6ms)  BEGIN
2018-09-17T19:07:22.997442+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-17T19:07:22.997336 #4] DEBUG -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78]   User Exists (2.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 AND "users"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["username", "Listy"], ["id", 65], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-09-17T19:07:23.002441+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-17T19:07:23.002365 #4] DEBUG -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78]   User Update (2.9ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "token" = $1, "token_expiry" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["token", "EAADxC9YDD2sBAKeTKx0Cgp86Dnm5l774a2vVsZBYwOTnl7TV9egMgBYjTtgY9lFHV6eW90V1KgRspbcHM3mKL92hKPO0fZAVbkNaWjdHzJ8TQiaRYJqZC3NnhNu6GOOr6eFtteA48XWhYXQslchLmFgUky1G50ZD"], ["token_expiry", "2018-11-16 19:07:22"], ["updated_at", "2018-09-17 19:07:22.997902"], ["id", 65]]
2018-09-17T19:07:23.055468+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-17T19:07:23.055339 #4] DEBUG -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78]    (6.5ms)  COMMIT
2018-09-17T19:07:23.063263+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-17T19:07:23.063174 #4]  INFO -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 99ms (Searchkick: 6.4ms | ActiveRecord: 19.1ms)
2018-09-17T19:07:23.064786+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-17T19:07:23.064718 #4] FATAL -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78]
2018-09-17T19:07:23.062638+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-09-17T19:07:23.062529 #4] DEBUG -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78]   User Store (6.4ms)  {"id":65,"exception":["NoMethodError","undefined method `connect_timeout=' for #\u003cTyphoeus::Request:0x000000000782ded8\u003e"],"exception_object":"undefined method `connect_timeout=' for #\u003cTyphoeus::Request:0x000000000782ded8\u003e"}
2018-09-17T19:07:23.065029+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-17T19:07:23.064965 #4] FATAL -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78] NoMethodError (undefined method `connect_timeout=' for #<Typhoeus::Request:0x000000000782ded8>):
2018-09-17T19:07:23.065153+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-17T19:07:23.065087 #4] FATAL -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78]
2018-09-17T19:07:23.065246+00:00 app[web.1]: [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78] app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:3:in `facebook'
2018-09-17T19:07:23.065243+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-17T19:07:23.065187 #4] FATAL -- : [3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78] app/models/user.rb:76:in `find_for_facebook_oauth'
2018-09-17T19:07:23.067245+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path= "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code= AQDCk0zcgI3_D0ZEuO5l6pWjAbhRgSelpfYcPB_f70hwffFdhs2MRp1rYd1fktORGUhqruLXbB40DXbbbx71zMHD2hH5UyndDQXbWpZ4gIoDuGVqO6IgFMwQuv0Jp_-PVQ2eokb_aW_ZfVY_LkIYPUWqy4fGihmWgd3S4cSlpo9zqV_0m9Ra4avOXQjw5a8VQEq2WNlIsun4J77x4EBzrOh_9xtVG582YV2pZy6tFE83QsvsmNkpBEzmWsV0bnGek94hbnbkpKRmImHfCLD5iyJ3HWZ3uQLG3FypdGZHjo8BtQ23Y2GeD5lnsyGlvqGRX4M&state=f58628a503514d6fd368e47a88f0f1c383e1dbe519b4ad09" host=www.listy.club request_id=3d25cc49-e2ec-4593-bf2f-d06d5595cd78 fwd="213.190.86.42" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=630ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
2018-09-17T19:08:50.249219+00:00 heroku[run.8341]: Process exited with status 0
```

Comment: Can you debug this line `undefined method 'connect_timeout=' for #<Typhoeus::Request:0x000000000782ded8` ?

Comment: How do I do this in production? Sorry, I am rather new to coding. When in development I simply put a debug command where I want the code to stop and then I debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, some people were able to solve this issue by adding the following code into an initializer, try it out:

```
require 'typhoeus'
require 'typhoeus/adapters/faraday'
```

Source: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/362